# How to get rid of 'Failed to load IMAP envelope' Messaging Exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to get the list of emails by `Message msg[] = folder.getMessages();`. After that I am getting the details of each message, meanwhile I am getting `javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope` exception for some message.

This is protocol trace for the one message which producing error -

```
A7 FETCH 2 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 2 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 2567 INTERNALDATE "29-Apr-2011 13:49:01 +0000" ENVELOPE ("Fri, 29 Apr 2011 19:19:01 +0530" "I NEES YOUR ASSISANCE?????" (("Mr Leung Cheung" NIL "info" "milium.com.br")) (("Mr Leung Cheung" NIL "info" "milium.com.br")) ((NIL NIL "mr.leung_cheung" "live.hk")) () NIL NIL NIL "<20110429134718.70333732030A@mail2.milium.com.br>"))
A7 OK FETCH Completed
```

Stacktrace of error is-

```
Failed to load IMAP envelope stacktrace: javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1276)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSentDate(IMAPMessage.java:377)
    at com.my.main.model.TestMail.showAllMails(TestMail.java:95)
    at com.my.main.model.TestMail.main(TestMail.java:45)
```

I am using JavaMail-1.5.

How can I resolve this error, is there any way or settings to solve it and get details of message without skipping that message?

Thanks,

Neelam Sharma

Answer (score 2):

Your server is broken.  Please report this error to the server vendor.  What server are you using?

In the response, the message's "To" value must meet this syntax defined in the spec:

```
env-to      = "(" 1*address ")" / nil
address     = "(" addr-name SP addr-adl SP addr-mailbox SP addr-host ")"
```

Instead, the server has returned "()".  It should've returned "NIL" if there is no To header.

You can work around server bugs using the technique described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I am using IMAP Server for getting message of Yahoo account. Using the option provided at - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug solving the issue of getting message content. But how can I get a message that throw "Failed to load IMAP envelope" using SearchTerm mentioned at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891509/how-to-get-message-from-messageidterm-for-yahoo-imap-profile Is this possible to get that message via MessageID? It there other way to get such message via MessageID??

Comment: Instead of using MessageIDTerm, use HeaderTerm and check the Message-ID header.

Comment: Again thanks, but I am not able to get message via SearchTerm searchTerm = new HeaderTerm("Message-ID", strMessageID); Message[] foundMessages = folder.search(searchTerm); though my message contains header called "Message-ID". This search return zero message. I am working for Yahoo IMAP server. How to get message?

Comment: Use message.match(searchTerm).  It will ask the server for the header, which it will compare locally, instead of asking the server to do the search.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your help, can you please suggest a way that is more  appropriate to get message (if I have message-id) either by getting message array earlier then perform message.match(headerTerm) on each message OR SearchTerm that I have mentioned in my reply at thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891509/how-to-get-message-from-messageidterm-for-yahoo-imap-profile

Comment: You can use the Folder.fetch method to prefetch the headers in one operation, thus reducing the cost of checking each message.